# Azure Graph API Password attribute of User object is always NULL

Tags: azure, active-directory

When retrieving users from Azure AD using the Graph API everything seems to work fine apart from the Password field not being populated.
I'm using version 0.8 of the contract (hence Password is still there, not been turned into PasswordProfile yet)

Any ideas as to why?
I could really use the hashed password value.
Our AD is fully housed in the cloud so the password has to be there; it could not be held by an on-premise AD instance as there is none.

Comment: FYI I also tried with contract version 0.9 but that returns passwordProfile=NULL.

Comment: you shall not use Preview contracts. Base your application on the GA contract: `2013-04-05` There will only be PasswordProfile

Comment: Thanks, I did that - unfortunately passwordProfile is still NULL :-(